# Post title in fancybox jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

How can i call to the post title in this code in fancybox?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("a.popup, a[rel=group]").fancybox({
        closeClick : true,
        helpers : {
            overlay : {
                locked : false
            }
        }     
    });

    jQuery(".video-popup").fancybox({
        'width'             : '70%',
        'height'            : '80%',
        'autoScale'         : false,
        'type'              : 'iframe',
        closeClick : true,
        helpers : {
            overlay : {
                locked : false
            }
        }     
    });

    jQuery('.menu a').click(function(){
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href').replace('#filter=','').replace(',+.menu', '');
        jQuery('.element.portfolio a.popup').attr('data-fancybox-group', 'invisible');
        jQuery('a.popup', href).attr('data-fancybox-group', 'visible');

    });

});
```

Comment: it may be as simple as adding a title attribute to your elements

Comment: Thanks for the response, you can give an example written code?

Comment: sure - show me a section of your html that appears in the fancybox

Comment: further question as I may have misunderstood your intent.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a WordPress site, I presented the home page posts, some of the posts from presenting an image and video display part, all the posts are opened fancybox posts which present a opening and below the picture has the title of the post, those that show video not show the title of the post.

Comment: Does the html markup for the embedded videos have a `title` attribute? i.e. `<a href="[YouTube video reference]" ` **`title="some title"`** `...>`

Comment: Yes i have somting like that

Comment: "something like that"...???  FancyBox will take the `title` attribute text and display it when the popup opens.  It must be the title attribute of the elements being passed to fancybox()